# Import Android APK Expansion libraries error

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have followed the steps on [Android dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing) to ste up the implementation of APK expansion pack for android on Google Play. I downloaded the two packages from SDk manager, imported each of them to Eclipse as library projects (just as follows on the link instrctuion) and I am receiving

`[2012-08-17 13:09:57 - library] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
[2012-08-17 13:09:57 - com.example.android.market.licensing.MainActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
[2012-08-17 13:09:57 - test] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'`

I fixed this by changing target API from 15 to 16 in the manifest.xml

But then when I assign the libvraries in my project's properties, another error pops up:

```
[2012-08-17 13:13:16 - MyApp ]     (skipping file '.nores' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-08-17 13:13:16 - MyApp ] invalid resource directory name: /Users/calvin/Desktop/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/res/res
```

What have I done wrong here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just battled this and figured it out - the `downloader_library/res` directory has an extra layer of nesting (no idea why). Moving `downloader_library/res/res` to `downloader_library/res` fixed this error for me.